# Algorithm for building tree depending on node attributes

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve a programming problem where I need to implement the following algorithm (roughly):

There are couple of nodes, ie, A, B, C, etc.

Every node can have multiple items in it, ie, a, b, c, x, y, z, etc. For example,

```
A [a, b, c, x, y, z]

B [a, b, c]

C [x, y, z]
```

There can be infinite number of nodes and items and nodes can have any number of items in it (but same item wont repeat again).

What I have to do is I have to create heirarchy among the nodes depending on the common items inside the nodes. So, in the above example, A should have higher heirarchy over B and C. Or in other words, A is master and B and C are the slaves.

So, I was thinking if I can make a tree from the nodes depending on common items, then it will be easier for me. But I don't know which algorithm to use. Anybody know which will be suitable for my case? Building tree is not mandatory, if there are other ways to achieve the same thing, it will be okay. Thanks.

Comment: Does the "master" (or parent) node need to contain all the items of its "slaves" (or children)? Or just as much as common with the children?

Comment: No, the master does not have to contain all the items from slaves. A node will be called master (here A) on other nodes (B, C) because it has the most common items among them. If there is a fourth and fifth item like D[a,b,c,x,p,q,r], E[p,q,r] then D would be master item here.

Comment: (continuation of my previous comment) And the level will be 2 level if you think as tree: Root (D) has two branch (A, E), A has two branch (B, C). Hope it is understandable.

Comment: Sounds like a [Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  Can you define the ordering of two nodes precisely based on their contents?  How would [a, b, c, d, e, f] sort compared with A?

Comment: So, if you have (say) 255 nodes, will you always have 8 levels from root to leaf?

Comment: @IanMercer I am not sure if I understand your question fully. But there are not sorting of items necessary, and more specifically, items are physical entities like files, audios, videos, emails, contact, etc. So no sorting exists in them I guess. Edited: I edited this comment as I think it was misleading.

Comment: @IanMercer But Topological Search looks good and promising for my problem. Going to check it. Thanks.

Comment: @DariusX. No, levels are dynamic, can have any length of levels

Comment: When you say "higher" in the hierarchy that implies some kind of ordering between *nodes* (i.e. a sort order).  So, which comes higher [a, b, c, x, y, z] or [a, b, c, d, e, f]? or are they "equal"?  Can you define more precisely what you mean by "higher"? Is it X < Y if X is strictly contained in Y? Or is it X < Y if X intersects with Y and X has fewer elements? or ...?

Comment: @IanMercer "X < Y if X intersects with Y and X has fewer elements" - this is the correct one. For example, X is a task with (a, b, c, d, e, f....) sub tasks. Y is a task which comprise of (a) sub task, Z is another task with sub task (a, c, f). I want to be able to say that, if I am working on Y or Z, then I am actually working on X. So, here X is on higher than Y and Z only because Y and Z has common and less sub task than X. Now if you consider Y and Z only, then Z is higher than Y because Y has common (a) and fewer subtask. So, if I am working on Y, I am actually working on Z.

Comment: @All: Thanks a lot for all of your help. I have got a solution. Please check my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted the algorithm proposed by the paper "Data Mining for Path Traversal Patterns in a Web Environment" by Ming-Syan Chen, Jong Soo Park and Philip S. Yu. This paper is available  [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.9534&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Though the algorithm here directly does not solve my problem, but I did little bit adaptation in the algorithm so that it fits my problem situation. Now it works fine and I get the result I need.

I would like to thank everyone took time to read my question and proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Note that the worst case for AVL trees may look something like [this](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/avl/avlmuchbal.png). You can read more about the worst case [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/avl/libavl_281.html).

Most importantly, given two 'nodes' does the logic to compare them and determine which is higher exist? If not then that needs to be built first!

Once you know how to compare, then AVL trees can be used to build and maintain the 'hierarchy'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already got a solution. Please check my answer about that solution.